# bootstrap-select shrinks when using inside jquery ui accordion under the input-group class

Tags: css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

I want use bootstrap-select and this is what I get:

[image]

The link to see: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp9xbhrL/1/)

Having this code:

```
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
      <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
        <option>test</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

It works only if I remove one of these things from my code:

```
1) input-group  (bootstrap)
OR
2) $("#accordion").accordion({}); (jquery ui accordion)
```

Then I found out that these two files have influence on showing select correctly:

```
jquery-ui.min.css
jquery-ui.theme.min.css
```

So, I've been going through and removing classes one by one and found out that there is one in both files (if you use both) which makes all the trouble:

```
.ui-widget input,
.ui-widget select,
.ui-widget textarea,
.ui-widget button {
    font-family: freesans,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

**If you remove the line `font-size: 1em;` everything start working again.**

I'm thinking what I'm losing by removing this line, I can't notice any difference in my situation. I'm glad it's working now.

Comment: This seems to be working just fine -  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp9xbhrL/). Are you using any custom CSS ?

Comment: Could you please provide HTML instead of PHP, can't tell what exactly your PHP `echo`s, so i can't exclude errors in your HTML.

Comment: it's not php because if I remove and just add <option>test</option> it's still showing wrong. I don't use custom CSS for input-group or selectpicker. It's really strange that it works in above jsfiddle, I don't know where to look in my code.

Comment: For the next time, include your complied HTML instead of PHP when asking for help with CSS. Inspect your elements in Firebug, Chrome or some other inspector. Chances are you have some custom CSS, as @DavidDomain mentioned, that messes up your page.

Comment: I edited my post and changed, also added extra note at the end.

Comment: Pretty obvious that your jQuery UI breaks Bootstrap, why do you have to use it? Also i found [this](https://github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/jquery-ui-bootstrap) with a quick google, might fix your issues.

Comment: I edited my post for the last time (I hope :). I finally got it working as it is suppose to.